# Регулярные выражения, split

Tags: python, re

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разделить ещё по нижнему подчёркиванию, чтобы были отдельные слова и остались символы

```
import re
s = "dolhy_sews'on_the_"
result = re.split(r'(\W+)', s)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
s = "dolhy_sews'on_the_"
result = re.findall(r'\w+', s.replace("_", " ").replace("'", " "))
print(result)
```

Можно просто заменить символы `_` и `'` на `"  "` ,а затем разделить на отдельные слова.

```
['dolhy', 'sews', 'on', 'the']

[Program finished]
```

А можно и без регулярки обойтись:

```
result = s.replace("_", " ").replace("'", " ").split()
```

Или полностью через регулярку:

```
import re
s = "dolhy_sews'on_the_"
result = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

`r'[_\W]+'`: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##HcqxCoAgEIDh3acQF5OipbnnaKhw6UDBVO4uwqe/pPX//to4lLyIxLsWZI2gSK/aXCWF5glesiV7DuCNQqAncVeEmWqKPKDd/bGdo500OVUx5t7@y4l8)

```
import re
s = "dolhy_sews'on_the_"
result = re.split(r'[_\W]+', s)
print(result)
```

Впрочем, пустая строка остаётся.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. А как сделать , чтобы остались символы?

Comment: @Iryna, ничего не понял.

Answer (score 0):

```python
import re
s = "dolhy_sews'on_the_"
result = re.split('\'|_', s)
print(result)
# ['dolhy', 'sews', 'on', 'the', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+|.", s)
```

Вот, что мне нужно было